# Filter for Google Analytics API

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to run this query with rGoogleAnalytics but it's throwing the error

```
Error in ParseDataFeedJSON(GA.Data) : 
  code : 400 Reason : Invalid value 'ga:pagePath=~/companies/[0-9]{6,8};ga:pagePath!@reviews' for filters parameter
```

I'm trying to fetch pages matching the pattern /companies/ followed by 6-8 numbers and not containing reviews

```
  query.list <- Init(start.date = "2016-01-01",
                     end.date = "2017-03-31",
                     dimensions = "ga:pagePath",
                     metrics = "ga:pageviews",
                     filters = "ga:pagePath=~\/companies\/[0-9]{6,9};ga:pagePath!@reviews",
                     max.results = 10000,
                     table.id = "ga:xxxxxx")
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to get as close as you can using the [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and share the link here. It will make it much easier for folks to help reproduce your issue and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is with your use of `{6,9}`. Perhaps you can Try to url encode that part of your regular expression: `%7B6%2C9%7D`

Use the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2017-01-01&end-date=2017-03-13&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D~%2Fcompanies%2F%5B0-9%5D%257B6%252C9%257D%3Bga%3ApagePath!%40reviews) to play with your query until you find one that works with what you are trying to accomplish.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterExpressions) states **URL-reserved characters** — Characters such as `&` must be url-encoded